# iOS 8 - How to determine the foreground app as well as get list of running apps

Tags: ios, ios8, reverse-engineering, iphone-privateapi

On iOS 7.0 and below, `SBFrontmostApplicationDisplayIdentifier` from the **Springboard** framework specified the app running in the foreground, but that capability has been blocked (considered as a vulnerability, see the Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures page dedicated to it [here](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-4361)) in iOS 8.

Does anyone have an **iOS 8** alternative for this?

Comment: if you found anything alternative then please share here..!!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do it on iOS 8 since a vulnerability was discovered. More info here: http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-4361